# How to repair bash on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash

Once I tried to open terminal in my Ubuntu 18.04 but it didn't work (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> too). I'am tired of searching on forums by two days so I decided to ask a question here. I think that problem in bash and probably somehow I broke it.
So I tried to run `xterm` which returns "Command not found", and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't work too.
I got Ubuntu installed alongside Windows.
Also there is some strange "Update error" at top-right corner which says "Error Message - A problem occured when checking for the updates"  (button Show updates and Preferences doesn't work) but in Settings->Updates No any updates.

Comment: I replaced file `.bashrc` in my home folder by  `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. After this tried to run terminal which didn't open.

Comment: System restart also didn't help

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is something's wrong in your .bashrc
try to rewrite it to default. like this:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi

export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Comment: To “reset” the `.bashrc` one can simply copy the default over: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @DewaSembiring I replaced file `.bashrc` in my home folder by `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. After this tried to run terminal which didn't open. System restart also didn't help

Comment: .bashrc file is default, but maybe file in /bin/bash is not executable , try to change it executable. # chmod 755 /bin/bash

Comment: @DewaSembiring How to change chmod without terminal?

Comment: @DewaSembiring in file properties executable is set to anyone. Is that what you mean?

Comment: forget about chmod. yeap, and make sure if the file permissions is read & write too